# Rescued 7 pounder at puppy stage very receptive to people, now barks, growls and sometimes will bite

Tags: dogs

We rescued a Pomeranian Schnauzer mix as a puppy and was 7 oz.  We took him to our office to keep an eye on him with another one of our younger dogs.  We kept these two at the office and our other two dogs who were older were left at our home.

When our older dog passed away we took the two younger dogs home to stay with our then oldest dog.  After our next oldest passed away we decided to bring the two Peekapoo and the Pomeranian Schnauzer mix back to the office.  Our once little 7 oz puppy, now a 7 pounder 10 year old has become very aggressive to people he does not know at our office.  This includes new employees, our customers, or anyone who happens to come into our office. We have them in my office behind a gate, but our 7-pounder will run to the gate and start barking and growling and jumping up and down at the gate, and we ask people not to put their hands near or over the gate.  I don't know if he will bite or not.

Once he gets used to the individual, he is just as loving and kind.  We have watched Lucky Dog and have read articles on the internet on how to stop this type of behavior (By trying to get his attention with a treat, etc.).  We don't know what to do any longer and don't want to physically punish him we want to figure out what is wrong and help him with it.  We believe he is scared since he was a rescue and don't know what to do to help him.

What we do today is shut the door so he won't act this way, but he just continues to bark and we will tell him to stop or go to his bed and stay.  We want to be able to not worry about how he is going to react when others come into the office he does not know.  He is such a loving and adorable dog and he brings joy to the office and everyone who sees him wants to pet and love on him, but we are concerned he might get upset and bite them. We can't even keep them out at our home when family comes over unless it is family he knows.

We want him to be a part of the family gatherings.  We want to be able to take him places with us.  Our now oldest dog is 17 and living on God's grace time according to our vet and leaving the 7 lb dog is not an option once our oldest passes away. We don't want to leave him at home by himself.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Everytime the first question: did you ask the vet, if the dog may have this temper because of pain? And next: how do you react, when the dog starts barking?

Answer (score 3):

Despite being smaller, Mini Schnauzers have... really strong guard instincts. They are also very very vocal and excitable.  They're telling you there's a stranger there.

As the former owner of a Schnauzer cross - you need to get people to ignore him when he barks, and reward *appropriate* interactions. If you're giving him treats when he's barky, he's associating the treat with the guard dog behavior. He did good! He gets treats! He even gets attention!

They are smart dogs *but* environment matters a lot - and the behaviours you reinforce.